# I want to install tensorflow version 1.14 in Google colab but failed

Tags: google-colaboratory

I need to test a code in Google colab which is not supported in tf2(for tf.ceil is not supported in tf2), so I want to install tensorflow in version 1.14. I use pip3 and pip to install tensorflow, all of them install tf successfully, but as I do this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

It returns:

```
'2.2.0-rc3'
```

And I have clear sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

It returns:

```
[]
```

How can I install tensorflow in version 1.14?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to ensure you work with TF v1 is to simply run the

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

line **before** you import TensorFlow.

Colab already builds TF from source so Google recommends against using `pip` to install TF as you may incur performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: as of 2023, **it is no longer possible to install Tensorflow 1 in a standard Colab runtime**. This is because Tensorflow 1.X requires Python 3.7 or older, and the standard Colab runtime now uses Python 3.10.

---

*Previous answer:*

If `sys.path` is empty, your Python environment is in a very bad state. You should reset your VM (*Runtime -> Factory reset Runtime*) and then run the following:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

Once you do this, you will have tensorflow 1.14 installed:

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```

```
1.14.0
```

Be aware that reseting your VM will cause you to lose all program state from your current session.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore as Google Colab has removed support for Tensorflow 1.x

Comment: Thanks - I edited the answer with updated information.